# Remote debugging tomcat8 server with intelij idea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, tomcat8

Im trying to setup a debug environment with my remote tomcat8 server (Ubuntu) running a .war servlet application. It is set for 9090 port.

What I did:

1. Uncommented this code in the /etc/default/tomcat8 file.

JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

2. called /etc/init.d/tomcat8 restart

I have then set a new remote configuration in my IDE using the server's ip address & port 8000

I assume then that when i call **myIpAddress:9090/warapp/someMethod** that I will get a response or stop at a breakpoint when I start a debug session but nothing happens. 
Just receive:
Error running 'Tomcat': Unable to open debugger port (myIpAddress:8000): java.net.ConnectException "Operation timed out (Connection timed out)"

Am I missing something here?

Comment: *You* would never call on the 8000 port. The debugger built into the IDE makes those "calls". You access your webapp as normal, i.e. on port 9090, and if you've set any breakpoints in the source code in your IDE, the program execute will stop on such a breakpoint when you do something in the webapp to make that code execute.

Comment: address=8000 should be some other port. You can't have tomcat and debugger running on same port.

Comment: The IDE may not be able to connect if there is an OS firewall blocking port 8000. Try specifying `address=localhost:8000` and configuring the IDE to connect using `localhost`. Or configure the firewall to open port 8000.

Comment: @kosa OP already said that Tomcat is running on port 9090, so 8000 should be available.

Comment: @Andreas Don't have any firewall on my Mac. None that I know of

Comment: @Andreas I missed it. OP, if Tomcat running on 9090 why your url is? myIpAddress:8000/warapp/someMethod

Comment: My mistake. I was assuming that if I open port 8000 to debugging as it states in the tomcat8 file that i would have to call it that way. In any case as you said. I am trying calling the api using port 9090. Api is being called but still not stopping at any debug point and getting the "Unable to open debugger port"...

Comment: And the IDE shows always: Connecting to the target VM, address: '109.207.76.69:8000', transport: 'socket'. I assume it needs to write connected at some point?

Comment: Check firewall settings on remote host.

Comment: Im sorry. I'm kind of new to this. And yes I want to try the localhost like you suggested @Andreas. Just don't know where. On my /etc/hosts file? My firewall is tuned off by the way

Comment: After adding port 8000 to remote firewall using: ufw allow 8000 I get connection refused from my IDE. Guess I made a mess of it.

Comment: Thank u all for your help. I managed to get it working combining all suggestions. I opened port 8000 in the remote firewall using ufw and created an ssh tunnel using ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 user@remotemachine. Works now.